# How to superimpose a small bitmap onto a larger bitmap in C at a certain x, y position?

Tags: c, bitmap, bit-manipulation

I am trying to write a program that detects pixel collision (overlapping of bits that have a value of 1) between two bitmap images. I know the position of the left side, right side, top and bottom of each bitmap in x and y coordinates relative to the LCD screen. My thinking is that I could superimpose the first bitmap onto a large, blank (0's everywhere) bitmap that is the size of the screen, at its x and y position. Then do the same for the second on it's own canvas. After that I could do a binary & operation of the two bitmaps that are of the same size. If the result is greater than 1, I know some of the pixels have overlapped.

The problem with this is I don't know how to superimpose two bitmaps. Does anyone have experience with this who could offer some advice?

EDIT: We are expected to use bitwise and bit-shifting operations to detect pixel level collision, with a maximum of 1 for loop.

Comment: Why don't you just write a loop that compares pixels? Copying the whole data is not conceptually wrong, but it is something that should be generally avoided because it costs memory and CPU. In particular, if afterwards you will have to do bit comparisons nonetheless.

Comment: To be honest it's because I can't decipher the library we use that writes the pixels to the screen as it is a bit more advanced than where I am in the course I'm doing. I am not sure exactly how to find the location/coordinates of the pixels. But also we are instructed that we should be using bitwise and bit-shifting operations.

Comment: Show which library you are using. Add tag if available.